# Creating .reg files

Tags: php, registry, mime-types

I need export some data from a web application into Windows .reg files

I've managed to create the file and force a download.

```
$tmpfname = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), "reg_".time().rand()."_" );
$tmpfpath = sys_get_temp_dir() . $tmpfpath;
$handle   = fopen( $tmpfname, "w" );

fwrite( $handle, $string );

header( 'Content-type: application/force-download' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.time().'_import-'.$reg_folder.'.reg"' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
readfile( $tmpfpath );

fclose( $temp );
unlink( $tmpfpath );
```

The problem is such that once I run the downloaded .reg file, the registry editor opens as expected and askes about adding information[...]Are you sure?. Upon clicking yes I get the following error message

> Cannot import [file]: The specified file is not a registry script. You
>   can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor.

My file looks like this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions\Test Site]

"HostName"="hostname"
"UserName"="username"
"PasswordPlan"="password"
<newline>
<newline>
```

I'm not entirely sure how to output the file in a binary format compatible with the registry editor.

The content type of registry files are "Registration Entries" according to Windows 7's Set Associations application but I've tried setting the content type to this in the script but it's not recognised.

Comment: Well, it's just a text format. How does *your* file look? Which encoding did you use? And did you try a correct MIME type, and Content-Charset? (`/force-download` is just silly)

Comment: I've tried using the content type "Registry Entries" but that just outputs the file as .reg.htm. I'm not sure what other type. My file looks exactly the same as one directly imported from the registry using regedit- but will add it to the question in a second. I haven't tried setting a Content-Charset.

Comment: The file must be UTF-16 or UCS-2 encoded. Please try with `wget -S` and debug the retreived file. A UTF-8 BOM etc in your PHP script would screw this. (Use a hexeditor to verify). Also `"Registry Entries"` is not a valid MIME type. Which exact value did you use?

Comment: Plain Passwords FTW. That you don't manage to pass a file properly while you inject WinSCP profiles is really scary.

Comment: WinSCP encrypts it when it detects the PasswordPlain registry entry. I've already asked on the WinSCP forum and Martin Prikryl replied saying do it this way. I'd requested information on how to reproduce the encryption algorithm and he said import it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not entirely sure how to output the file in a binary format compatible with the registry editor.

I think that is the cause of your problem. You need to create the file based on it's file-format specification. The mime-type is less important here, windows works more with file-endings (.reg) than mime-types. You just need to take care that you use the right mime-type with your file-format. For that you need to know the file-format, too.

To which specific file-format specification are you referring to? Are you sure you want to create a binary .reg file and not a textual one?

Comment: I'm unsure whether binary/text is the format I need. I am only asuming binary as that's what the error said. The file has the .reg extension and I can double click it, it tries to import it just like any other registry file but fails with the error message in the question.

Comment: Well I can not tell you as it's not my file, you need to say. You can give any file any file extension, so that it has `.reg` at the end of the filename does not says much. That it fails on import by regedit just means that you have provided an invalid formatted file. Compare the files content against the file-format specification. That specification is still missing, can you please provide it?